# symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, armv7, xcode6.1

I have read many posts on symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7  SO and none of the proposed solutions are working for me. I am hoping someone who knows a little more about interpreting errors can help.

Deployment Target 6.0

Xcode SDk:- 6.1

Link binary with libraries :-- I have Add  libPods.a

Header Search path:-- I have add path :-- ${SRCROOT}/Pods

Architectures:-- armv7

Valid Architectures :-- armv7

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestOperation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RWStripeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RWStripeViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Comment: What's header search path got to do with the linker? You want library search path.

Comment: Check all the places where you imported RWStripeViewController, either its duplicating in .h and .m both or you have imported RWStripeViewController.m rather than .h file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check wheter RWStripeViewController is properly defined in interface and implementation(check spelling too) and also check wheter RWStripeViewController.m is added to target